# How to do query with two different date and time SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT 
    c_emp_user, SUM(cantidad) AS Cantidad 
FROM 
    bulto_paquete_mined 
WHERE  
    n_contrato = '888' 
    AND fecha = '02-04-2018' 
    AND hora > '16:59' 
    AND (fecha = '03-04-2018' AND hora < '02:00')
GROUP BY 
    c_emp_user
```

This does not work, how do I have to do it instead?

In my work there is a shift that covers from 3:00 PM to 01:00 AM, then I need that query show me all that happens in this hours

Comment: Hi Alex. You'll get better help if you share more information. Give this a read through, then edit your question. https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: please be patient, i dont know speak english but i try to do it as i try to code and do querys

Comment: @AlexRodríguez  . . . What is the data type of fecha?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You main problem is working with string. Convert everything to datetime. Note sure if your date is format mm-dd-yyyy or dd-mm-yyyy, you need take that in consideration so the cast work. Right now receive mm-dd-yyyy

```
SELECT *
FROM Yourtable
WHERE  Cast( CONCAT (fecha, ' ', hora) as datetime )
            BETWEEN Cast( '2018-04-02 16:59' as datetime) 
                AND Cast( '2018-04-03 02:00' as datetime)
```

Comment: in my case is dd-mm-yyyy

Comment: Me imagine ... por que eres de chile. Sabes que hay una version en espanol de esto? https://es.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: Per the OP, they want to know what happens over a given time frame that crosses over days. Your query constraint does not answer that problem.

Comment: @JWeezy . . . This answer most definitely does handle the issue of crossing over different days.  And, assuming `fecha` is in the right format, it even returns correct results, which is a bit better than your attempted answers.

Comment: that works for me! thanks

Comment: Alex save yourself from big headaches in the future and start using  datetime fields instead of string on the future. Leave the date format to the UI.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza in fact it is field was already as datetime but I separated it without knowing what I was doing

Comment: Ok, then is easier. As @GordonLinoff pointed you just need add both date and time to get the right value. dont need do any cast for those

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `fecha` and `hora` are stored as a date/time, then you can do the following.  This seems like a reasonable assumption for columns called "date" and "time".

In SQL Server you can add date times together.  So you can do:

```
SELECT c_emp_user, sum(cantidad) as Cantidad 
FROM bulto_paquete_mined 
WHERE n_contrato = 888 AND
      (cast(fecha as datetime) + cast(hora as datetime)) >= '2018-04-02 17:00:00' AND
      (cast(fecha as datetime) + cast(hora as datetime)) < '2018-04-03 01:00:00' 
GROUP BY c_emp_user;
```

This will, ironically, also work with strings.  However, for it to understand the OP's dates correctly, the internationalization settings have to recognize the DMY format.  However, that is irrelevant if the correct data types are being used.

Answer (score -2):

Use the BETWEEN operator.

```
SELECT c_emp_user, sum(cantidad) as Cantidad 
FROM bulto_paquete_mined 
WHERE  n_contrato='888' 
    AND fecha BETWEEN '02-04-2018' AND '03-04-2018'
    AND (hora BETWEEN '00:01' AND '02:00'
        OR hora BETWEEN '16:59' AND '24:00')
```

Note: it is unusual to separate the date and time into separate columns or variables. The above query should only give you results between the given date range and further constrained by the time of day.

If date and time are in separate columns and you want to know what happens only between the hours of 3pm to 1am between the date range of 02-04-2018 and 03-04-2018 then the above query will work. In this case, it is beneficial that the date and time are split out.

**Update:**
The query is expected to return all results for the following ranges:

1.) 02/04/2018 00:01 - 02:00

2.) 02/04/2018 16:59 - 23:59

3.) 03/04/2018 00:01 - 02:00

4.) 03/04/2018 16:59 - 23:59

If the OP does not want the trailing time ranges (i.e., 1 and 4 above), then add a constraint to remove them.

Comment: that doesnt work. you can be at 1am of day 2 and wont show up

Comment: I had the times reversed. I have corrected it.

Comment: again, the ranges wont match.

Comment: Note: 1am is still outside of the provided time range. If you are looking for starting time of 16:59 to end time 02:00 then the query constraint changes. In other words, the start and end time crosses over days. Is that the intent?

Comment: the problem is you can have `'02-04-2018 00:00'` and  that will be returned with your query, But shift start at `'02-04-2018 15:00'`

Comment: I already updated my answer to account for time periods that go from beginning of day to end time and beginning time to end of day. This will account for a specific time range between 1 + n number of days. The OP has mixed the start and end times between what is in the code versus what is in the question. But, the same concept holds.

Comment: check again `'02-04-2018 00:00'` shouldnt be on the range and right now it is.

Comment: You still dont see it? You cant use OR for time. because everything from `'02-04-2018 00:00'` to `'02-04-2018 02:00'` will match and that is from previous shift day.

Comment: I have the OR wrapped in parenthesis.